# Django Rest Framework: 'base_template' for inserting datetime field in browseable api view

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Django rest framework I am using ListCreateView. One of my fields contain publish_date. It shows the following way

[image]

I want to have the date time picker just like in the django admin which shows as follows:

[image]

I know in Django rest framework we can mention the template:

```
style={'base_template': 'input.html'}
```

So how to achieve this because i didnt find any template for date time picker in the rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

The way your field is presented is determined by the serializers.py setup you got.
An alternative solution to creating a home-made HTML solution will be to take advantage of the **DataTimeField()** field in your serializer.

I.E:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

    class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        created = serializers.DateTimeField()

        class Meta:
            model = Comment
```

More about this subject in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield).

Comment: Its DateTimeField() only. It does not show any date picker